# Moment.js - get current date with predefined time

Tags: jquery, momentjs

```
moment("17-Jan-2017 12:00 pm", "DD-MMM-YYYY hh:mm a")
```

Using moment.js, I can't work out how create the current date with a predefined time. I thought this might work:

```
moment(moment(new Date()).format("DD/MM/YYYY") + " 12:00 pm", "DD-MMM-YYYY hh:mm a");
```

But it doesn't - how can I build that datetime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set it using the [set function](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/set/) like this:

```
moment().set({ hour: 12, minute: 0, second: 0, millisecond: 0 });
```

And then format that using the [format function](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/):

```
moment().set({ hour: 12, minute: 0, second: 0, millisecond: 0 })
        .format("DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm:ss");
```

**Updated -** 
Now also includes the setting of the `second` and `millisecond` to prevent those from being taken from the current date/time. A much better approach is @MattJohnsons answer which uses [parsing](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/).

Comment: This sorta works, but it has the side effect of seconds and lower being set based on the current time, rather then zero.  Better to start with good data, rather than starting somewhere else and adjusting.  But thanks.

Comment: @MattJohnson yes, good shout. I did think that at the time of posting but thought in the context of the original question it was somewhat irrelevant so tried to keep it short and sweet. You're right though, it's certainly a better practice to reset everything to zero. Updated the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

The preferred way would be to set the time during the initial construction.  You can use either:

```
moment("12:00", "HH:mm")
```

or

```
moment({ hour: 12, minute: 0})
```

The date portion will be resolved to the current date, and anything seconds or lower will be set to zero.

Comment: I saw this in the activity feed...I was like, I didn't answer that!

Comment: @MatthewJohnson - It's a good name.  Glad to make your acquaintance!

Comment: This is certainly the better approach and should be the answer. I've learnt something new. Thanks for the feedback.